# Expo, React, Change State within a Snack Template

Tags: react-native, expo, status

I created a new Snack.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CIM_Header />
      <View style={styles.fixToText}>
        <Button
          title="Left button"
[---]
```

I just want to make the simplest thing, change a state.
So I checked the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/state/) which is complex, there is an overridden `render()` function with later a `render(){...}(?)` syntax.

I understand I just need to access the `this.state` variable, so I imported *Component* but I still can't access *this*.

I tried this way (I saw a constructor can be used):

```
export default function App() {

constructor(){
 this.state.mystate = true;
};
```

which doesn't work because *App()* apparently is not a *Component*, so I tried to extend it

```
export default function App() extends Component {
```

Which I know is weird, because App() is a function, but I tried anyway since all the syntax is quite strange. Anyway it also doesn't work because the unexpected token or Syntax error.

I tried to create another object extending Component as I saw in the tutorial, also doesn't work. The tutorial is built on another different syntax.

```
class Blink extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Toggle the state every second
    setInterval(
      () => this.setState(previousState => ({ isShowingText: !previousState.isShowingText })),
      1000
    );
  }
```

So I need help to **change a state from the scratch Snack template**.

Side Question: how can I follow the tutorials from Expo if in the tutorials *App* is a class and in the Snatch *App* is a function() which happens to change everything.

Comment: Here is a good example of a functional component which use `useState` to manage the state: https://daveceddia.com/usestate-hook-examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a trivial example of setting state in a function component. While it's not using react native, it demonstrates the same concept.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);
  return <div>
    <button onClick={() => {
      setHidden(!hidden);
    }}>Click me</button>
    { !hidden ? <span>Maybe visible?</span> : null }
    </div>
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-allen-07vt0)

Comment: This is just what I was asking for.

It raises so many questions: where should I have learned about useState(), what is the difference by components and functional components...  but you gave me already few important tips on where to search for tutorials. Thank you Evan.

Comment: In terms of what you can achieve, there's not much difference between the function vs class components, however the ecosystem is definitely moving toward the function side, so if you're just starting out I'd say stick to that.